# Component not part of NgModule

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, module, components

I'm working on an application that uses Ionic for school, but am still pretty new to all this. Everything was working fine until I tried to link two pages that are involved in the login process, since then I've been getting errors whenever I try to compile the site.

Uncaught Error: Component LoginPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:26121)

LoginPage does get called when I use it in login.module, but I honestly don't know what steps to take from here on out, the application itself is built from a tutorial 'prototype' so to speak that I have been making changes in, so it's very possible I'm overlooking something fundamental to the way the tutorial application was supposed to work.

As the error arose after I tried to configure some things in regards to routing I will be posting the relevant code below. Here is the app-routing-module.ts file

```
//import { AuthGuardService } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPage } from './public/login/login.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  //{ path: 'register', loadChildren: './public/register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { path: 'submit', component: LoginPage },
  // { 
  //   path: 'members', 
  //   //canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  //   loadChildren: './members/member-routing.module#MemberRoutingModule'
  // },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

(as you can see I've commented out some code that shouldn't be necessary to my application, I've tried uncommenting this but it didn't solve the error.)

What I'm trying to accomplish right now is to move from the first page you see, whose html file should be bound to the following: login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPageModule
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {
  pageDirect() {
    this.router.navigate([`/submit`])
  }
}
```

To the page where the actual logging in happens, bound to the following file: login.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  id: any;
  key: any;
  user_data: any;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  token;

  login( username, password ) {
    console.log(username, password)
    const url = `https://svsdb.woodl.nl:5555/api/public/auth/login`;
    const data = {
      email: username,
      password: password,
    }
    console.log(data)
    this.httpClient.post(url, data).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.message)
        this.token = res.data.token.value
        this.id = res.data.user._id
        console.log(this.id)
        this.readUser(res.data.user._id)
        this.key = res.message
      },
      (error)=>console.log(error),
      ()=>console.log(),
    )
  }

  readUser(userId) {
    const url = `https://svsdb.woodl.nl:5555/api/user/read/${userId}`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        authorization: this.token,
      }
    }
    this.httpClient.get(url, options).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
        this.user_data = res.data
        sessionStorage.setItem(this.id, JSON.stringify(this.user_data))
        console.log(this.key)
        this.getData()
        this.redirect(this.key, this.id)
      },
      (error)=>{

      },
      ()=>{

      }
    )
  }

  getData(){
    console.log(this.user_data)
    return this.user_data
  }

  redirect(message, id) {
    if (message === "Logged in.") {
      console.log("success")
      console.log(this.user_data)
      this.router.navigate([`/profile/${id}`])
    }
    else if (message === "Password incorrect, please try again") {

    }
    else if (message === "No user registered with this e-mail") {

    }
    else {
      console.log("fail")
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Right now when I try to just visit localhost, I get the following error: Uncaught Error: Component LoginPage is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (compiler.js:26121) (some more lines but I figure this conveys the gist of it)

To summarize, I am trying to get from the first html page which contains a login button, to the actual logging in page where you submit the data and call the login function that you can see in login.page.ts. I've tried a couple things but only keep getting different errors, I'm afraid if I just continue 'trying' stuff I'll mess up the files beyond repair. Any help will be immensely appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
as requested here is the app module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Show your App/root module please

Comment: @xyz Hey, just uploaded it

Comment: Import your `LoginPageModule` in your App module

Comment: can you route to a module as you have done over there as te component property should accept only components.If you have lazy modules then a lazily loaded module is something that you should try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import LoginPageModule in your app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    LoginPageModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```